# In docker-compose. How to set a volume for other user than root?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  httpd:
     build: ./etc/httpd/
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 8080:80
     volumes:
       - ./www:/var/www/html
     links:
       - maria_db

  maria_db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```

And this ./etc/php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

And when it is run:
$ docker-compose up --build -d

The directory that bind the the volume is only for root:

```
$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  4 md   md   4096 feb 12 02:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 md   md   4096 feb 11 03:01 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 md   md    395 feb 12 02:39 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  3 md   md   4096 feb 12 01:55 etc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 feb 12 02:42 www
```

I have tried to create before the directory and other things...but not.

Comment: don't spam with tags irrelevant for your question!

Comment: I am trying with a more simple docker containers (a debian with a user bind mount the home user):

`version: '2'

services:
  debian:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - './caca:/home/newuser'
    tty: true`

And the Dockerfile:

`FROM debian:jessie

RUN useradd -rms /bin/bash newuser
RUN chown -R newuser:newuser /home/newuser


USER newuser

WORKDIR /home/newuser`

But it still set a root the outside volume and the folder of user.

Answer (score -1):

A job mate helped me...it is easy:

It is necessary the bind mount directory exist before to docker-compose because the docker-compose make the directory for root user.